# Holding a button to keep sending a variable in serial

Tags: c#, loops, button

I am trying to do an app that comunicates with arduino and it needs an input from serial to move a servo. I made something but I need to keep clicking the button to send a variable to serial but I need it to work just like a button so if I hold it down it keep sending variables to serial.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("z");
        }

        private void button4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("c");
        }

        private void button1_MoseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("a");
        }
                
        private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("d");
        }

       
    }
}
```

and here is the arduino

```
#include<Servo.h> // include server library
Servo ser;
Servo ser1;// create servo object to control a servo
int poser = 0; // initial position of server
int val; // initial value of input

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Serial comm begin at 9600bps
  ser.attach(9);// server is connected at pin 9
  
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) // if serial value is available 
  {
    val = Serial.read();// then read the serial value
    if (val == 'd') //if value input is equals to d
    {
      poser += 1; //than position of servo motor increases by 1 ( anti clockwise)
      ser.write(poser);// the servo will move according to position 
      delay(10);//delay for the servo to get to the position
     }
    if (val == 'a') //if value input is equals to a
    {
      poser -= 1; //than position of servo motor decreases by 1 (clockwise)
      ser.write(poser);// the servo will move according to position 
      delay(10);//delay for the servo to get to the position
    }
     if (val == 'c') //if value input is equals to d
    {
      poser += 10; //than position of servo motor increases by 1 ( anti clockwise)
      ser.write(poser);// the servo will move according to position 
      delay(10);//delay for the servo to get to the position
  }
  if (val == 'z') //if value input is equals to a
    {
      poser -= 10; //than position of servo motor decreases by 1 (clockwise)
      ser.write(poser);// the servo will move according to position 
      delay(10);//delay for the servo to get to the position
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Set a flag when the button is `down` and unset the flag when the button is `up`. Run a task using TPL and have that check the state of the flag and send the serial message on a set interval. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Comment: You can also use a timer - there's a built in `Timer` class in `System.Threading` that will fire an event every X interval where X can be any time span. It essentially raises an event when the time has elapsed.

Comment: you need a RepeatButton this control exist in WPF but i dont know if exist in winforms or not

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a task with a cancellation token. From [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      CancellationTokenSource taskATokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

      private void button1_MoseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
        Task.Run(TaskA(taskATokenSource.Token), taskATokenSource.Token);
      }

      private void button1_MoseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
        taskATokenSource.Cancel();
      }

      private Action TaskA(CancellationToken ct)
      {
        //For example only
        //Needs slowed down or some other way to prevent input buffer from overflowing.
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("a");
        }

        return null;
      }
```